# using new keyword in post api with mongoose showing typeerror

Tags: javascript, api, mongoose, post

I am working on POST api with mongoose fetching data through POSTMAN api and connected to mongodb.
i got stuck in program where its showing typerror and thats why i am not able to fetch data its an minor error but help me if you know:

**ERROR: in index.js**
**let data = new Product(req.body);
^
TypeError: Product is not a constructor**

1. **config.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/ecomm');
```

2. **product.js**

```
const { Module } = require('module');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    name:String,
    brand:String,
    category:String,
    price:Number
  });
Module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
```

3. **index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
require('./config');

const Product = require('./product');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.post('/create', async(req,resp)=>{
   
   let data = new Product(req.body);
   let result = await data.save();
   console.log(result);
   resp.send(result);
})

app.listen(3000);
```

i passed throgh terminal data it worked while using new keyword in index.js and postman api its showing error.

Comment: can you paste what's inside product.js ?

Comment: In json format ::  [{ "_id": { "$oid": "6449df163fe8f8114ae22fbf" }, "name": "AS", "brand": "Sony", "price": 15000, "category": "mobile" },{ "_id": { "$oid": "644afd9c3fe8f8114ae22fc2" }, "name": "asdf", "brand": "vivo", "price": 25000, "category": "mobile" }]

Comment: I got the solution, I have done changes in config.js  ------>>>const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);
mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/ecomm", { useNewUrlParser: true ,  useUnifiedTopology: true 
 });

Comment: cool! Good to hear that